# Accessing a Datatable in JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have Stored my Datatable in a Session variable as

```
Session["dt"]=dt;
```

and I am accessing it in the Javascript for some purpose as

```
var oTable = '<%=Session["dt"] %>';
var oRows = oTable.fnGetNodes(); // Error here     
for (var i = 0; i < oRows.length; i++) {

var x = parseInt(cells.push($(oRows[i]).find("td:eq(1)").html()));
}
```

but it throws the error **Object does not Support this property** what could be going wrong kindly any one help

**Edit :**
For Your Information I am just getting the datatable to fetch the Values in it and use it for some condition

I had found via your answers without serilization it may not be possible so I had serialized the data and passed the value to hiddenfield I had done as follows

```
 myArray[0] = new { Flag = dt.Rows[0]["Flag"].ToString(), 
                    status = dt1.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString() };
 JavaScriptSerializer serializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();

 sbAllUsers = serializer1.Serialize(myArray);
 hfvalue.Value = sbAllUsers;
```

but I dont know how to access this value in Jquery kindly anyone help me.

Comment: I think you need to convert your datatable to an HTML string and then call the `.datatable()` function on THAT string.

Comment: you have to first convert the Session value to the appropriate type because session store object type value.

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/q/10492791/3660930

Comment: @rajesh could you pl upvote if its really helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned below create a list of anynomous class from DataTable and serialize using `JavaScriptSerializer`. and set the result in hiddenfield `hdnControl`, now on client side get the value from hidden field and parse it into the JSON, now you can access the data.

**C#**

```
JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var Result = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
              select new
              {
                  Flag = c.Field<bool>("Flag"),
                  Status = c.Field<string>("Status")
              }).ToList();

hdnControl.Value = oSerializer.Serialize(Result);
```

**Javascript**

```
var oTable = JSON.parse($("#hdnControl").val());
$(oTable).each(function(index, val){
    console.log(val.Flag);
    console.log(val.Status);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Object does not support .... --> is a Javascript error...

You cannot overhand a complex type like this.
You have to serialize it first to string format --> JSON string or a normal string.

Perhaps this post might help you, how to serialize a datatable into a json string:
[Convert datatable to JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        ICollection<MessageDTO> list = new List<MessageDTO>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var obj = new MessageDTO() { UserId = i, DateCreated = DateTime.Now, Content = i.ToString(), ChatRoomId = 1, MessageId = i };
            list.Add(obj);
        }

        MyCustomStringProp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    }

    public string MyCustomStringProp { get; set; }
```

Fetching the data from Javascript:
--> Download the following JSON script and reference it in ur page:
[JSON2.js](http://www.JSON.org/js.html)

```
 var oTable = '<%= this.MyCustomStringProp %>';
            var parsed = JSON.parse(oTable);
            alert(oTable);
```